# Byobu: Disable Shift+Arrow keys when in zoomed mode

Tags: shortcut-keys, byobu

Firstly, love byobu. Kudos to the developers!

After using it for a while, I have started into this workflow pattern where I zoom into the main pane and work on it in vim for a while, and then move back to my command pane to run some commands.

To zoom into one pane, I use the `Shift+F11` command, and then `Shift+F11` again to move back.

One thing I found annoying is it's very easy to hit `Shift + Arrow Keys` whenever I am in vim (I use selections a lot), and that seems to force byobu to get out of zoom-pane mode. I am sure it is useful in some cases.

Is there a way I can disable it for my use-case, somewhere in a `.byobu/config`? I've looked around and haven't found any documentation on suppressing keystrokes in certain modes, and I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few things, but it's not easy.

What you'd need would be two different commands, one for zooming into a split, and a different one for zooming out.  You can add this to your local `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf` and then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> to zoom in, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> to zoom out:

```
bind-key -n S-F11 resize-pane -Z \; unbind-key -n S-Up \; unbind-key -n S-Down \; unbind-key -n S-Left \; unbind-key -n S-Right
bind-key -n M-F11 resize-pane -Z \; bind-key -n S-Up select-pane -U \; bind-key -n S-Down select-pane -D \; bind-key -n S-Left select-pane -L \; bind-key -n S-Right select-pane -R
```

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Thanks @Dustin, this gives me a good starting ground to get things going!

Comment: @Dustin, Shift + F11 doesn't work on my mac. There is no zoom in the help page ("C+a ?"), too.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Ctrl-a shortcut in tmux (see tmux(1) manpage).  You could create your own, but there are few, if any, single keys available.  If you do, you want to bind the command "resize-pane -Z".